# nested property propertychanged event only fired once in usercontrol in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, dependency-properties, propertychanged

There are two Viewmodels, both of them had implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (I have called the `OnpropertyChanged("propertyname")` in my actual code).

```
    Public Class A{
        public B BProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _BProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_BProperty != null)
                    _BProperty.PropertyChanged -= _BProperty_PropertyChanged;
                _BProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BProperty");
                if (_BProperty != null)
                    _BProperty.PropertyChanged += _BProperty_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        void _BProperty_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "status")
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("BProperty");
            }
        }
        B _BProperty;

}



Public Class B
{
   public int status{get;set;}
}
```

I also had a `userControl`:

```
<MyUserControl  ...
                ... >
   <Grid>
   </Grid>
</MyUserControl>
```

And I had a dependencyProperty:

```
/// <summary>
/// File status
/// </summary>
public int Filestatus
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(FilestatusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilestatusProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilestatusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Filestatus",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(0, OnFilestatusPropertyChanged));

private static void OnFilestatusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl control = (MyUserControl)d;

    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
    }
}
```

edit:2015/09/21
Add the get/set methods:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FileStatusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
"FileStatus", typeof(int), typeof(FileStatusIconControl), new PropertyMetadata(0, PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static int GetFileStatus(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (int)source.GetValue(FileStatusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFileStatus(DependencyObject target, int value)
    {
        target.SetValue(FileStatusProperty, value);
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        FileStatusIconControl fsic = dependencyObject as FileStatusIconControl;
        if(fsic != null)
            wahahahahaha;
    }
```

edit end

I used this userControl in my mainPage like this:

```
<mainPage ...
          ...>
  <Grid>
    <MyUserControl Filestatus={Binding Bproperty.status} />
    <TextBox Text={Binding Bproperty.status} />
  </Grid>
</mainPage>
```

The datacontext of mainPage is an instance of Class A.

My question is:
When status is changed, the text of textbox is changed, but the `OnFilestatusPropertyChanged` method only was called once when `Usercontrol` is loaded. Why?
Thanks.

Comment: I found my solution. I had wrote wrong DependencyProperty. I just declare a DependencyProperty, without no Get/Set method. so the callback never be called. After I added them. it worked very well. See the detailed code above.

Answer (score 2):

I will start by saying that while I was looking into your question I ran into some problems with the code you have provided.  I appreciate that somewhere you have some real code which has a problem and you cannot share this code with us so have tried to reproduce the problem in a smaller set of files.

However, if you do do this, please at least verify that the code you have provided runs and exhibits the problem.  It is evident that you haven't tried to run your sample code (particularly the XAML) as there are problems with it:

- attribute values should be surrounded in double-quotes,
- the binding path `Bproperty.status` should be `BProperty.status` (first `P` capitalised).

All these things slow down someone trying to help you.  Worse still, when I do find a problem with your code I can't be sure whether it's a genuine problem that your real code also has or whether it's something you introduced putting together your sample code.  So all I can do is point out all the problems I find in the hope that one of them is the problem you have in your real code.

Firstly, your `TextBox`'s `Text` property binding doesn't contain `Mode=TwoWay`.  In WPF, this binding is `TwoWay` by default, but in Silverlight all bindings are `OneWay` by default.  If you are familiar with WPF, this may be why you omitted `Mode=TwoWay`.

Secondly, I don't see why you have implemented class `B` as you have, apparently leaving it up to class `A` to fire property-changed events on its behalf.  This approach doesn't work: when Silverlight updates the value in the `status` property of a `B` instance, it does so by calling the `status` setter of the `B` instance.  Your `B` class has only an autogenerated property setter, which certainly doesn't fire the `PropertyChanged` event.  Because this event wasn't fired, Silverlight doesn't know that is has some updates to do, and furthermore your `A` class isn't aware that it has changed either.

I would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the usual way in class `B`, by calling `OnPropertyChanged` in the `status` setter.  I would also remove the `BProperty_PropertyChanged` event handler in class `A` as I don't think it does you any favours.

Comment: Thank you Luke, I have found my solution.

Comment: @user5305463 which is your solution?